# ios apple push-notification server side design

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our app users can login their accounts and if a user is logged in, then he can receive push notifications when someone added him as a friend. Based on my understanding, our server needs to record the userID and its notification token, so that any events happened to the userID, the server can find its token and send to apple APN. If this token is changed, we also need to update the record in server. I am not quite sure if my understanding is correct or not. anyone can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to store on your server a unique ID for each user and its notification token. You should update this token stored on your server with a connection in AppDelegate method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". Everytime something happens, as a new friend request, your server have to send a new push notification using the stored token.

Comment: You mentioned that I need to created a unique ID. Should I generate this id from app and send it to our server with userID and token? Or should the server generate this ID and send back to app and app shall store it?

Comment: This unique ID is created and managed by you. Basically, you use this ID to identify users, it can be an incremental integer or the nickname too for example. When a user complete the registration, you can save his nickname on server and his token in the same row of database. So, if i want to add user "john" from my application, i can send a request to the server, and the server can send the notification with the token associated  to nickname john. The same thing can be done with incremental id.